# Difficulty reproducing LaTeX codes from the TUG India website

Tags: errors, tutorials

I am new to LaTeX. I downloaded all files listed in the [TUG India website](http://www.tug.org.in/tutorial/). I tried to `pdflatex` their code with no success. I wrote to them twice and received no response.
Could someone help me `pdflatex` these files to reproduce their beautiful 17 chapters ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: What was the errors ? and which source code was used. Is this [ltxprimer-src-1.0.tar.gz](http://sarovar.org/frs/download.php/121/ltxprimer-src-1.0.tar.gz) ? BTW you can [submit all issues](http://sarovar.org/tracker/?atid=273&group_id=48&func=browse), No Idea whether [CVR](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/18704/cv-radhakrishnan) and others maintainers are still active on site. Some of them are built on [custom classes developed by TUG India](http://sarovar.org/users/cvr/) . What's wrong with using the [screen or print](http://www.tug.org.in/tutorial/chap17-scr.pdf) version of  Chap 17.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a look to the sources you have linked you will find an file named `tutor.tex`. Download **all** given files into a new directory on your computer. Then compile `tutor.tex` (be aware to receive errors, the code is a little bit old).

An first run shows something like 155 errors, starting with an `\theoremstyle`.

To get rid of these errors (but showing 11 pages) a little research has to be done.  It seems that `amsthm` has changed since the document was written. The option `mystyles` with content in file `mystyles.thm` does not work.

So change in file `tutor.tex` line 22 to the following (adding `mystyles.thm` into the main file):

```
%\usepackage[mystyles]{amsthm} %  <=========== line 22
\usepackage{amsthm}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{thmsec}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{cor}[thmsec]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lem}[thmsec]{Lemma}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{dfn}{Definition}[section]

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{note}{Note}[section]


\newtheoremstyle{mystyle}{}{}{\slshape}{}{\scshape}{.}{ }{}
\theoremstyle{mystyle}
\newtheorem{mythm}{Theorem}[section]

\newtheoremstyle{mynewstyle}{3pt}{3pt}{\itshape}{}{\sffamily}{:}{\newline}{}
\theoremstyle{mynewstyle}
\newtheorem{mynewthm}{Theorem}[section]


\newtheoremstyle{diffnotenonum}{}{}{\itshape}{}{\bfseries}{.}{ }%
  {#1 (\mdseries #3)}
\theoremstyle{diffnotenonum}
\newtheorem{Cauchy}{Cauchy's Theorem}
\newtheorem{Riemann}{Riemann Mapping Theorem}

\newtheoremstyle{newdiffnotenonum}{}{}{\itshape}{}{\bfseries}{.}{ }%
  {\thmname{#1}\thmnote{( \mdseries #3)}}
\theoremstyle{newdiffnotenonum}
\newtheorem{newRiemann}{Riemann Mapping Theorem}

\newtheoremstyle{citing}{}{}{\itshape}{}{\bfseries}{.}%
  { }{\thmnote{#3}}
\theoremstyle{citing}
\newtheorem{cit}{}

\newtheorem*{numlessthm}{Theorem}

\swapnumbers
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{numfirstthm}{Theorem}[section]
```

Now I got only one error I can live with:

> bibliography not compatible with natbib

You receive the screen version as result. If you want the print version just add the class option `print` in file `tutor.tex`.